# space of solutions of a PDE

Tags: partial-differential-equations, vector-spaces

> Suppose $\phi(x, y)=X(x) Y(y)$ is a nontrivial separated solution of the Helmholtz equation $\frac{\partial^{2} \phi}{\partial x^{2}}+\frac{\partial^{2} \phi}{\partial y^{2}}=K \phi$ satisfying the boundary conditions $X(0)=X(1)=0, Y(0)=Y(1)=0$
>
> **(a)** Show that $\phi(x, y)=C \sin (p x) \sin (q y)$ for some $p, q \in \pi \mathbf{Z}, C \in \mathbf{R}$
>
> **(b)** Deduce that if there is a nontrivial separated solution then $K \in \pi^{2} \mathbf{Z}$
>
> **(c)** If $K=-2 \pi^{2},$ deduce that the only solutions have the form $C \sin (\pi x) \sin (\pi y), C \in \mathbf{R}$ and sketch the graph of such a solution.
>
> **(d)** How many solutions can you find when $K=-5 \pi^{2} ?$ When $K=-50 \pi^{2} ?$
>
> **(e)** Why is the space of solutions to the Helmholtz equation (for fixed $K$ ) a vector space? What is its dimension?

so I have just completed part (c) and I'm now on part (d).

To fill you in, I have found that $K = -\pi^2 (n^2+m^2)$ for some $n,m \in \mathbb{Z}$ and $p = n\pi, q = m\pi$

now I don't really understand what they mean by "how many solutions", take for instance $K = -5\pi^2$, we get then $5 = n^2 + m^2$, implying that $n = 1, m = 2$ or $n = 2, m = 1$ (as if we get $n = -1, m = -2$ we get the same solution as $n  = 1, m = 2$ due to sin being odd).

Now, taking these we get the solutions to be in the form of $\sin(\pi x)\sin(2\pi y) $ or $\sin(2\pi x)\sin(\pi y)$ does this mean we have two solutions? I'm not really sure how this relates to the number of solutions we can find and I certainly don't see how this can be a vector space (for part e)

Comment: Well, are $\sin\pi x\sin\pi 2y$ and $\sin2\pi x\sin\pi y$ the same function? In any case, by «number of solutions» they probably mean number of «linearly independent solutions».

Comment: @MarianoSuárez-Alvarez No... I don't believe they are

Comment: If they are not the same function then you have two solutions.

Comment: @MarianoSuárez-Alvarez but I mean I don't really understand how the two soltuions can be linked in to a the equation being a vector space, I mean for $K = -50\pi^2$ I get 3 solutions, but I really don't see the connection

Comment: I don't understand what you don't understand: what is to «link the two solutions in to a the equation being a vector space»? I don't see what two things you are trying to connect.

Comment: The fact that the set of solutions of the equation (for a fixed K) is a vector space is just a fact of nature, a consequence of the equation being linear homogeneous).

Comment: @MarianoSuárez-Alvarez I don't really see how it is a fact of nature - I mean, for a fixed K we get a fixed amount of solutions, how does this mean the equation is a vector space?

Comment: The set of solutions of a linear homogeneous PDE is **always** a vector space: that is, in fact, almost what it means for the equation to be linear and homogeneous!

Comment: On the other hand: the statement of the problem makes no implication that one can deduce that the set of solutions for a fixed K is a vector space from the fact that there is «a fixed amount of solutions». As I said, the two things are completely independent.

Comment: @MarianoSuárez-Alvarez really? I mean I figured part (e) would follow from part (d) somehow... would I be right in saying the dimension of the PDE is two, but how can I find the dimension of the set of the solutions?